# list in recursive function is getting reset

Tags: c#

Inside a recursive function I append elements to a list (IEnumerable) that I gave the function as a parameter.

Somethig like this:

```
public class FooObject {
   private string Name;
   private List<FooObject>? Childs;
   
   public void RecursiveFunction(IEnumerable<FooObject> excludeList) {
      if (!excludeList.Any(x => x.Name == this.Name))
         return;

      excludeList = excludeList.Append(this);

      foreach (var child in this.Childs) {
         child.RecursiveFunction(excludeList);
      }
   }
}
```

The problem is that for example in a depth of 3 it appended an element to the list and has no child elements so finishes and goes up to depth 2 again and there the appended element from depth 3 isn't in the list anymore.

Is this behavior intended or do I missunderstand something in the concept of function parameters and pointers?

Comment: `excludeList = excludeList.Append(this);` creates a new `Enumerable` and changes what the variable that is local to the method refers to. That will not modify any other (existing) `Enumerable`

Comment: You modify the variable not the object that you have passed, similar as: `var excludeList = new List<FooObject>(); excludeList  = otherList;`. You need to pass a real list and use it's `Add` method

Comment: Pretty sure you should just do this excludeList.Append(this); This will append the element, not create a new list and overwrite the existing one, which is what I assume you are tryin to achieve?

Comment: using List solved it
@JosipJuros no that won't work since the linq opperations dont modify the original

Comment: @JosipJuros The documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.append?view=net-6.0) specifies that `excludeList.Append` creates and returns a new sequence. It does not modify the original one (an assignment will not change how this method works))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assign a different enumerable to the variable `excludeList`, similar as:

```
var excludeList = originalList; 
excludeList = otherList; // now originalList is not changed, of course
```

You need to let the method take a real list and use it's `Add` method

```
public void RecursiveFunction(List<FooObject> excludeList) {
  if (excludeList.Any(x => x.Name == this.Name))
     return;

  excludeList.Add(this);
  foreach (var child in this.Childs) {
     child.RecursiveFunction(excludeList);
  }
}
```

If you want to support more collection as just a `List<T>` you could allow `ICollection<T>`.