# How do I return a list from inside a recursive function?

Tags: c#, list, recursion

I am trying to use a recursive method to return a list but I can not figure out how to preserve the data in the list and send it back to the caller. The list gets reset on each iteration.

This is what i have until now:

```
List<InsuranceMenuItem> insuranceMenuItemsList = new List<InsuranceMenuItem>();
List<InsuranceMenuItem> checktest = new List<InsuranceMenuItem>();
insuranceMenuItemsList = ParseDynamicTreeview((InsurancePartDynamicObject)oInsuranceDynPart, checktest);
```

And this is the recursive method:

```
private List<InsuranceMenuItem> ParseDynamicTreeview(InsurancePartDynamicObject oInsuranceDynPart, List<InsuranceMenuItem> checktest)
    {
        InsuranceMenuItem insuranceMenuItem = new InsuranceMenuItem();
        InsurancePartBase[] oInsuranceParts = oInsuranceDynPart.GetAllInsuranceParts();
        
        foreach (InsurancePartDynamicObject oInsuranceDynP in oInsuranceParts)
        {
            insuranceMenuItem.name = oInsuranceDynP.Caption;
            insuranceMenuItem.id = Utilities.GetDBInt(oInsuranceDynP.ProductDefinitionObject.DataRow, "ProddefTypeID");
              
            checktest.Add(insuranceMenuItem);
            ParseDynamicTreeview(oInsuranceDynP, checktest);
        }
        return checktest;
  }
```

The problem is that "checktest" only contains the data that was fetched in the last loop.
In some way "chektest" gets reset on each iteration and I don't know how to fix it.
I was looking to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71352827/list-in-recursive-function-is-getting-reset) but I can't make it work.

Thanks!

Comment: Unless I miss something obvious the recursive part of the code looks fine to me. Can you please post a full [mre]? Have you tried to step through in the debugger (also try rebuilding and reruning)?

Comment: Wouldn't be the best solution but u can pass checktest by reference (ref List<InsuranceMenuItem> checktest)

Comment: It may be easier to make a static list in the class rather than to return values.  You can create a method to return the list separately.